# How can i block direct access to specific folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess

There is my problem, i have an img tag, src gets image from icon/ folder and i need to disable direct link access to that folder and content inside that when user type something like 'mywebsite.com/icon/logo.png', using htaccess, but allow content inside src attribute to get and display it without 403 error message 'access denied' in browser console, i made lot of research but nothing helped me, if i missing something please provide your opinions thanks.

my .htaccess code is here:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'http://mywebsite.com/icon/'">
        deny from all
    </If>
    <Else>
        allow from all
    </Else>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.  In PHP, when you send the HTML to the client, the client browser is responsible for loading those resources directly.  You don't send them with the HTML, just the links to them.

Comment: If your icons and content were SVGs you could potentially embed them in the HTML rather than linking to the files, but this would be messy with JS, CSS, and other resources.  Also, you deny the benefits of local caching of unchanged resources and the benefits of using a CDN

Comment: You can do by define some value and pass every request from that page and check if the value is defined then do further process otherwise die or msg

Comment: Robin Singh, could you provide some code for example please?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is disable it with webserver apache2. In my 14.X Ubuntu - open /etc/apache2/apache2.conf you have to change from

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

now just restart apache.

to restart apache2 run:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This will disable directory listing from all folder that apache2 serves.